# Share partition ubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, filesystems, operating-system

In order to have a partition accessible in both Ubuntu and Windows I had a drive formatted as fat32(or vfat) I just found out that it does not hold single files that are more than ~4.3Gb in size. Is there any other fs that is supported in both windows and linux? I would like to read and write from both OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried NTFS? It should work on both. Although you obviously will not have Unix permissions on that file system. But you should be able to mount it on both windows and Linux.

Comment: Here's a page with info on mounting an NTFS partition in Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: If you're running Windows 7 (or 8), sharing ntfs partitions between Windows and Linux (ESPECIALLY subdirectories of c:\Users) will cause endless pain and misery, courtesy of Explorer's refusal to allow administrators to touch files with unknown/mangled/ambiguous/alien ACL data unless you explicitly "take ownership" of them first. The shell (usually) doesn't care, but Explorer will stop you dead in your tracks every time, and Win32 apps will (usually) fail if they throw up a file dialog that enforces Explorer's new rules.

Comment: Also, every time you boot into Linux, the next time you boot into Windows, you'll be forced to run chkdisk. If you have 2-6 terabytes of data spread across multiple drives and partitions, you can EASILY spend 10-20 minutes waiting for chkdisk to finish. And... if you create a brand new ntfs filesystem under Linux, and populate it with files copied under Linux, but created under Windows (with Windows ACL info for an installation that no longer exists), may ${deity} help you the first time you boot into a new Win7/8 installation with that drive attached... chkdisk might take DAYS to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Linux can read and write to NTFS partitions using NTFS 3g. That's probably your best bet.

Other options include windows based utilities that can access ext-2, 3, or 4, but few integrate as a driver and the ones that do are apparently unreliable.